# How can fetch serialize data without last one?

Tags: php

I have a serialize data with N data, and I want to select N-1 data.
Example: i:38, i:39, i:41 data. I want to show i:38 and i:39 only.
Also I want to show all data except first one.
Example: i:38, i:39, i:41 data. I want to show i:39 and i:41 only.
Any suggestion or help?

Here is my serialize data:

```
a:3:{
i:38;a:2{s:12:"arrival_hour";s:5:"05:30";s:14:"departure_hour";s:5:"05:40";}
i:39;a:2:{s:12:"arrival_hour";s:5:"05:45";s:14:"departure_hour";s:5:"05:00";}
i:41;a:2:{s:12:"arrival_hour";s:5:"06:10";s:14:"departure_hour";s:5:"07:35";}
}
```

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: But that's not valid serialized data

Comment: RE: @AbraCadaver comment. Have you already messed with the original contents of your serialized string? If so, post the original vanilla string

Comment: can you show us the unserialized data?

Answer (score 0):

Just unserialize the data first, then you will get the output in an array format, after that you manipulate in whatever way you want.

$data = a:3:{
i:38;a:2{s:12:"arrival_hour";s:5:"05:30";s:14:"departure_hour";s:5:"05:40";}
i:39;a:2:{s:12:"arrival_hour";s:5:"05:45";s:14:"departure_hour";s:5:"05:00";}
i:41;a:2:{s:12:"arrival_hour";s:5:"06:10";s:14:"departure_hour";s:5:"07:35";}
}
$myArray = unserialize($data);
var_dump($myArray)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php